# merging Cesium and the Ozone Widget Framework

Tags: java, javascript, widget, cesiumjs

I am a fresh college graduate and at my new job I have been tasked with the job of merging two different applications. The applications are Cesium (a web-based service written in JavaScript, HTML and CSS) and the Ozone Widget Framework ( Written in JAVA). This seems like a fairly complex task to start out with. How would I go about doing this? or learning how to merge such technologies?

Advice/help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [OWF website](http://www.ozoneplatform.org/) says it already supports Cesium:

> A fully functional map widget that is designed to be extensible by other programs for their particular needs, and currently provides Google Earth, OpenLayers, Cesium and WorldWind renderers

I work on Cesium, but have never used OWF so I can't speak to the details.

There is also a Cesium plugin that provides [GWT wrappers](https://github.com/richkadel/cesium-gwt) for Java developers that may be of interest to you.

Patrick

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be very little documentation in the Ozone Widget Framework. In fact, a search for it has only yielded 6 results in Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

I have experience with both OWF and Cesium. OWF is particularly difficult, for the reasons mentioned here. Unless you're working in a community that does a lot with OWF, you're not going to get a lot of help.

Most likely the approach that will yield you the best results in a sane amount of time will be to create your own OWF widget (which can be just a page, like any other, that is imported through the admin tool or made available in a app/widget store). You could then use OZONE Synapse (ugh) to integrate with other widgets in OWF.

Cesium is a pretty darn good tool. I'm not really a fan of OWF for a number of reasons. If you can dissuade your employer from using it, that may be worthwhile. If it's a direct client requirement, then you'll probably want to see if you can join OWF specific developer communities.